# How do you damage the ?? level enemies?

Tags: destiny

In a couple of places in Russia in the Destiny Beta there are enemies with ?? over their heads instead of a level. They appear to be immune to every weapon.

Is there any way to damage them?

If not is there any way past them?

Comment: before the "unreleased" close votes come in. The game is now in public beta. Fair game.

Comment: If MMOs are any indication, they must be enemies with a level so high that you can't see it. A good example is World of Warcraft, happens the exact same thing.

Comment: I've actually gone past a place where enemies like this are and those enemies were no longer there.  Explored a little to find it was an empty room, nothing too exciting.

Comment: I read from somewhere that if the enemy is 4 levels higher than you, then it will become ??? and immune from your attack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `??` enemies are 4 or more levels higher than you, which means that you cannot damage them, only anger them.

Eventually you'll get high enough level to see their actual level and be able to damage them.

Answer (score 6):

I have not found a way to damage them or get past them.

They seem to be intended as a gating mechanism, to prevent exploration, as this is only a beta and they are trying to keep you within a given area.

Comment: better than invisible walls. +1 Bungie.

Comment: @Rapitor Destiny has invisible walls as well as invisible ceilings.

Comment: it also has places that look like you can go there and then insta-death when you step out of the invisible boundary, including some instances where it spawns chests in those areas!

Comment: They're still there in release, they're just too high level compared to you.